# How can I get Spooldir's output to append rather than replace?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

Can I get spooldir's output to append to a file if it exists rather than overwrite? I have the connector working correctly, the only issue is that if it consumes a file called, for example, log.txt, when it outputs it outputs a file called log.txt, which gets overwritten when a new logfile is consumed.

```
name=spooldirfile-source  
connector.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirLineDelimitedSourceConnector  
tasks.max=1  
topic=log-entry-test 
input.file.pattern=test.*\.txt  
input.path=/home/folder/kafka_2.13-2.4.0/temp/kin  
error.path=/home/folder/kafka_2.13-2.4.0/temp/kerror 
finished.path=/home/folder/kafka_2.13-2.4.0/temp/kout
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration? it's not quite clear from your question what you're asking

Comment: It's just a default spooldir-source connector.

```name=spooldirfile-source 
connector.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirLineDeli itedSourceConnector 
tasks.max=1 
topic=log-entry-test
input.path=/home/folder/kafka_2.13-2.4.0/temp/kin 
error.path=/home/folder/kafka_2.13-2.4.0/temp/kerror
input.file.pattern=test.*\.txt 
finished.path=/home/folder/kafka_2.13-2.4.0/temp/kout```

The problem is that the files being sent to kout are overwriting previous files if the input file has the same filename. I'd like the output to append instead of overwriting